# Parsing Meteor error: Exception from Deps afterFlush

Tags: meteor

I get these Deps errors from time to time and I can never figure out what they mean or what they're pointing to:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at eval (native)
    at http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:372:22
    at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:373:7)
    at jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text script (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9806:11)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:8873:18)
    at done (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9293:15)
    at callback (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9753:8)
    at Object.send (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9759:7)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.ajax (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9244:15)
    at Function.jQuery._evalUrl (http://localhost:4000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:9409:16) debug.js:41
```

It thinks that there is a syntax error, but the only files it points to are jquery.js, which I HIGHLY doubt contain errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by code in a Template helper somewhere that uses JQuery/a jquery plugin and is running code using `eval` which contains a syntax error in it, which is why it appears to come from JQuery itself.

There isn't much more than this to go off im afraid. It might be from ajax. Have a look at your chrome's network tab to see what is being downloaded just before this happens and see if it contains any javascript.

If it contains HTML when it should contain javascript check your Meteor paths, Meteor does not throw 404 errors, instead it serves out the main page's html, which may be why the error displays this way instead of a 404

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way in Chrome to go backwards through the call stack one by one and see where the problem originated from?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the similar "afterFlush" error, and while my error was also rooted in a jQuery/plugin with Meteor, it had nothing to do with eval.

The issue circled back around to updating the DOM at the same time I was updating a reactive method, where Meteor was also updating the DOM reactively. I found this out, and removed the manual DOM manipulation, which made this error go away. Hope someone else finds this helpful...